# How to get latitude & longitude in Fused Location APi

Tags: android

I am using Fused Location API to get latitude & longitude. My question is how can i set these value to other variables so that i can do some calculation or show them on my application. I have tried below code so far.

```
public class FusedLocationDetector implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener     {
private Activity context;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;
private double temp;
private String mib;
public LocationAddress locationAddress=new LocationAddress();

public FusedLocationDetector(Activity context) {
    mGoogleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    this.context=context;
//        locationAddress=new LocationAddress();
}

public  void startConnection(){
    if(mGoogleApiClient!=null){
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

public  void stopConnection(){
    if(mGoogleApiClient!=null){
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    fusedOperation();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

  //  mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}


public void fusedOperation(){
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mib= String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        locationAddress.setLatitude(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        locationAddress.setLongitude(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        Log.d("Longitude",String.valueOf(locationAddress.getLongitude()));
        Log.d("Longitude",mib);



    }
}
```

}

Comment: Latitude & Longaitude show on Logcat but does not set on any other varriable

Comment: Where is your variable

Comment: What do you mean when you say not able to set on any other variable? Explain?

Comment: here "mib" is a varriable where i set latitude value but when i want to use value of "mib" outside of those funcation then it show me null...